# How to get insights from a usability test?

Tags: usability, user-research, usability-testing

I am new in the UX world, as practice I have conducted a usability test, but I am having problems when identifying insights.

I have used an Affinity Diagram to organize my observations and come un with some patterns. A pattern I have identified is:

**4 of 5 users were cofused about how to make a schedule from the home screen**

A possible insight may be:

**For most of the users is not clear how to schedule a babysitter from the home screen**

What do you think? do you have a way to indentify insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your design insight could be "Users need a new way to schedule from home screen". However, it could be considered too specific to be an insight and would more be called a "finding".**

There is no precise definition of an insight, it is a statement that summarize research and that could have an impact.
**To know if it is an insight, ask these three questions :**

- Does it say something about the attitude, behaviour, needs or context of your users in general (i.e. is true, regardless of your product or solution)?
- Is it a fundamental principle you’ve discovered, like a behavioural or design pattern?
- Does it say something about your brand, product or service in its entirety and not just a small part of it?

**Can you answer at least one by "yes" ? It is an insight.**

(source : https://www.reveall.co/blog/how-to-write-valuable-user-insights)

From a usability test, you can have different types of insight depending on the nature of the study : quantitative or qualitative. In either, there is a ton of information, findings.
**For my part, to find insights, I start by sorting the problems by severity and frequency and look at the overall results.**

Here are the problem severity from usability.gov :

- Critical: If we do not fix this, users will not be able to complete the scenario.
- Serious: Many users will be frustrated if we do not fix this; they may give up.
- Minor: Users are annoyed, but this does not keep them from completing the scenario. This should be revisited later.

(source : https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/reporting-usability-test-results.html)

You can also use the rainbow sheet template to visually identify the more frequent issues :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but now I am kind of confused. I have read [link]( https://www.reveall.co/blog/how-to-write-valuable-user-insights) It mentions it is important that and insight help me to get to know ‘why' people behave the way they do(root cause), so in the case of having this finding: **4 of 5 users were cofused about how to make a schedule from the home screen** what insight responds to the ‘why'? **Users need a new way to schedule from home screen** or **For most of the users is not clear how to schedule a babysitter from the home screen**?

Comment: Good point. I have two answers depending on what we consider an insight. Don’t overthink it, it is not easy to formulate proper insight, but keep these points in mind.

Comment: **First answer, if we follow the “definition” from Reveal.com, we want an insight to be durable, to have an impact on long term.** Of course, we cannot know it for sure but we ask those questions to verify the minimum. I want to keep my insights because they can help decisions in one month, for me or for other people (marketing, etc.). Here, your propositions and mine are not insight because once I resolved my problem, I don’t have learn much for my future decisions. To be more valuable I would need, as you say, to discover why.

Comment: **Second answer, if we are broader about what we consider an insight and that is often the case in real world (but not for the better).** If we consider an insight any things valuable that we learn from research. There still the work to rephrase, summarise the research in a way efficient for your design/dev/work team. In this context, "Users need a new way to schedule from home screen could be an insight". Here, insight and findings are the same thing.

Comment: That's great! Now it makes more sense for me. Thank you so much for taking time to answer me. I really appreciate it

Comment: News definitions from Nielsen and Norman Group (NNG) 
(https://www.nngroup.com/articles/data-findings-insights-differences/) :

Findings = What Happened, Not Why.
Insights = Opportunities to the Business.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**, I just found new definitions of insight, fact, recommandation and experiment in a Atomic research conference of Daniel Pidcock. It can be useful.

"For most of the users is not clear how to schedule a babysitter from the home screen" is a an observation, so it is also a fact.

---

**Experiments** “We did this…”

**Facts** “…and we found out this…”

**Insights** “…which makes us think this…”

**Recommendations** “…so we’ll do that.”

[What is Atomic UX Research? Daniel Pidcock](https://blog.prototypr.io/what-is-atomic-research-e5d9fbc1285c)

---

**FACT**

**What we learned**

QUOTE

> “I can’t find the invoice section,  surely it should be here?  [points
> to profile dropdown]”

*OR*

OBSERVATION

> Participant 3 took 6 mins total to  find the invoice section and ended
> up in profile settings four times.

*OR*

STATISTIC

> 14% of support calls are clients  looking for copies of their invoice

SHOULD BE:

- Unbiased and hold no assumptions
- Short enough to read in a few seconds
- Contain or tagged with how it was learned and what contex

---

**INSIGHT**

**Why we think we found this**

CONTEXT

> Customers can’t find invoices

*AND/OR*

CAUSE

> …because they see invoices as  related to their personal paid  account
> rather than the product…

*AND/OR*

EFFECT

> …so they call the contact centre for  help.

SHOULD BE:

- Short enough to read in a few seconds
- Have enough context to be understood by itself
- Clearly defined relevance (such as a client or feature)

CAN BE:

- PRINCIPLE - Have relevance to as wide an audience as possible
- STRATEGIC - Help us understand a wide subject
- TACTICAL - Only relevant for specific context such as a feature